# GCP Managed Notebook undefined symbol: 'cublasLtGetStatusString' Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Restarting or deleting a new notebook and starting over still gets the same error. The attached GPU is a T4 or V100. Both don't work. How can I resolve this error?

```
OSError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so.11: undefined symbol: cublasLtGetStatusString, version libcublasLt.so.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Pytorch Notebook using the following settings:

`n1-standard-4` + `1 NVIDIA T4 GPU` from Google Cloud Console.

I use the following environment:

```
Environment: PyTorch 1.13 (with Intel® MKL-DNN/MKL)
Environment version: M108
```

Seems to be that GPU is recognized:

[image]

What environment did you configure and where do you see this error?
Please clarify by adding exact steps to reproduce.